In my react native expo app, when I send a new message, the new message appears on top for few seconds and disappears
I am working on react native (expo) private chat app, when I send a new message, the new message appears on top for few seconds and disappears.
that means, the new sent message should be at the bottom by default and it appears at the bottom after disappearing from the top after few seconds. The problem is very specific and very confusing to share. Please look at the pics and code.

const listenToMessages = (chatID) => {
        const chatDocRef = doc(firestore, 'Chats', chatID);
        const messagesCollectionRef = collection(chatDocRef, 'Messages');

        const messagesQuery = query(
            messagesCollectionRef,
            orderBy('timestamp', 'asc')
        );

        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(messagesQuery, (querySnapshot) => {
            const messages = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data()
            }));
            setNewMessage(messages)
        });

        return unsubscribe;
    };


    const sendMessage = async () => {
        if (input.trim()) {
            const newMessage = {
                from: currentUserUID,
                to: searchedUserUID,
                text: input,
                timestamp: serverTimestamp()
            };

            const chatDocRef = doc(firestore, 'Chats', chatID);
            const messagesCollectionRef = collection(chatDocRef, 'Messages');
            setInput('');
            await addDoc(messagesCollectionRef, newMessage);

        }
    };

    if (!loaded) {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    backgroundColor: '#171722',
                }}
            >
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#FF8C00" />
            </View>
        );
    }

    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            style={styles.container}
            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'padding'}
            keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 90 : 0} // Offset to handle the keyboard
        >

            <SafeAreaView style={[styles.container, { paddingTop: 0, marginTop: 0 }]}>
                <FlatList
                    ref={scrollRef}
                    overScrollMode="never"
                    style={styles.flatlist}
                    data={(messages || []).sort((a, b) => (a.timestamp || 0) - (b.timestamp || 0))}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                        <View
                            key={index}
                            style={
                                item.from === currentUserUID
                                    ? styles.sentMessage
                                    : styles.receivedMessage
                            }
                        >
                            <Text style={item.from === currentUserUID
                                ? styles.sentText
                                : styles.receivedText}>{item.text || ''}</Text>
                        </View>
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.timestamp}
                    onContentSizeChange={() => scrollRef.current?.scrollToEnd()
                    }
                    onLayout={() => scrollRef.current?.scrollToEnd({ animated: true })}
                />
                <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Type a message..."
                        value={input}
                        onChangeText={setInput}
                        placeholderTextColor={'rgba(128,128,128,0.6)'}
                        onSubmitEditing={sendMessage} // Send message on pressing enter
                        returnKeyType="send"
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={sendMessage}>
                        <Ionicons name='send' size={27} color={'#FF8C00'} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
};

"dependencies": {
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^12.2.1",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.14",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.18",
"expo": "~51.0.24",
"expo-application": "~5.9.1",
"expo-auth-session": "~5.5.2",
"expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
"expo-font": "~12.0.9",
"expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
"expo-random": "~14.0.1",
"expo-router": "~3.5.20",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
"firebase": "^10.12.5",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.74.3",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
"react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
"react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
"undefined": "expo/vector-icons/AntDesign",
"uuid": "^10.0.0",
"expo-notifications": "~0.28.15"

},
I have tried almost everything as much as I could do, I am new in React Native, so can't figure this. If there is any solution please help, the bug is small but very annoying to watch.

What dependencies do you use for the chat?

I have updated the question with the dependencies.
